# remove protocol property from WHATWG URL object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a little builder class that does url manipulation from a URL object, using the legacy node require('url') however now i am trying to migrate it to use the new WHATWG URL class.

In my builder class i had a method called removeProtocol() which does nothing more than removing the protocol so we can have convert to string urls like `test.com/path/go/somewhere` as opposed to `https://test.com/path/go/somewhere`

While the new class works much better than the legacy one. It does not accept the protocol to be an empty string, keeping it with previous value.

I tried things like:

```
delete this.url.protocol => this was ignored
delete this.url.__proto__.protocol => also results in the url being printed with the protocol.
```

removing the protocol from the href property also causes an error.

```
TypeError: Invalid URL: test.com/path/go/somewhere
```

Is there a way to do with this class. or does it mean I will have to convert the object to a string a remove it the protocol from the string?

Comment: Yes, you have to convert it to a string yourself. Notice that an `URL` instance represents a resolved, absolute URL. See also https://github.com/whatwg/url/issues/421

Comment: Regarding your attempt, [the docs](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_class_url) say: "*In accordance with browser conventions, all properties of `URL` objects are implemented as getters and setters on the class prototype, rather than as data properties on the object itself. Thus, unlike legacy `urlObjects`, using the `delete` keyword on any properties of URL objects (e.g. `delete myURL.protocol`, `delete myURL.pathname`, etc) has no effect but will still return true.*"

Comment: @Bergi thank you for the replies. deleting the properties were silly desperate attempts, tbh. I did read the spec as, that having a url in the constructor without a protocol constitutes an invalid url, i was surprised that they made sure that all properties were validating it also (as the previous url object in node didnt care at all. Thats for the issue link though i hadnt seen it in my searches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scheme (a.k.a. protocol) is a necessary part of a valid URL, and the WHATWG URL object represents a valid URL.

So, to answer your question: No, it's not possible to have a WHATWG URL object without a protocol.

Whai *is* possible is to extend the `URL` class:

```js
class ProtocollessURL extends URL {
  constructor(plURL, base) {
    super("http://" + plURL, base);
  }
  toString() {
    return this.host + this.pathname + this.search + this.hash;
  }
}

const url = new ProtocollessURL("google.com/search?q=hello+world#something");

console.log("Host: %s", url.host);
console.log('"URL": %s', url);
```

Comment: thank you for this. i dont get why on earth i didnt think of it. you sir just rocked my day.